# Segmentation fault involving unused variable

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

So I face a strange problem. When declaring an `int` that is not subsequently used, I get a segmentation fault. When I remove the declaration, the code runs perfectly. How can this be?

```
FILE* ptr = fopen("prueba.txt", "r");
int x;
char* a;
int y = 0; //this cause the seg fault. 
do{
    while (fscanf(ptr, "%i", &x)!=-1){
        fscanf(ptr, "%s", a);
            printf("%i    %s    ",x, a);
    }
    fseek(ptr, 0, SEEK_SET);
}while(1);


fclose(ptr);
}
```

But even if I use it, say with `y++;`, after `printf` I am still getting a segmentation fault.

Comment: fscanf(ptr, "%s", a); this looks like the problem. a is not malloced

Comment: `fscanf(ptr, "%s", a);` overwrites random memory. By adding a variable, you happen to change which random memory it stomps on.

Comment: @Art, too bad short answers get autochanged to comments. If you can get your answer to show up in the Answers section, it'll help keep this question from showing up in the "Unanswered" section forever.

Comment: @CDahn I didn't bother with a proper answer since this is a "debug this specific instance of my code" question. The answer will never be useful to anyone else.

Comment: @CDahn wait? That happens? Short answers get converted to comments?

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya, yes. I'm not sure what the criteria is, but if you give a short, one or two sentence answer, it auto commits it as a comment instead. Super annoying, but I guess it forces you to provide more details in the answer. Sometimes it makes answering very simple questions a bit challenging.

Answer (score 5):

> after printf I still getting seg. fault.

Well, segfault can be caused by cause A and get caught only after a while.

this line: `fscanf(ptr, "%s", a)` is reading string into `a` without allocating the memory first -> UB.

The UB is invoked only at `printf`. Fix the `a` with `a=malloc(SOME_SIZE)` or `char a[SOME_SIZE]` and this should go away

Answer (score 1):

You need to initialize your pointer to char, `char *a`, by using `calloc` or `malloc` functions. Alternatively, use arrays with automatic storage duration like `char a[20];`.

In your code, you are passing uninitialized pointer into `fscanf()` meaning effectively that `fscanf()` is going to overwrite to an *undefined area of memory*.

Comment: *use stack-allocated* it would be better if you change the wordings to "use arrays with automatic storage duration".